# Twitter API v1.1

Tags: php, api, twitter

I would like to get images posted in a tweet. I try to do this but it's not working :

```
<?php 
                $tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline',array('entities' =>10));
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($tweets as $k => $tweet): ?>
                <img src="<?= $result->$tweet->entities->media[0]->media_url; ?>"/>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

Can you help me?
I'm novice and not very confortable with php.

Thank you

Comment: What is $result here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given information I hope:

```
<img src="<?=$tweet->entities->media[0]->media_url; ?>"/>
```

Comment: @Julien_es Mark it as answer if that worked for you so that others can also refer this.